# to_date conversion not working from character hardcoding in the query, getting error 'ORA-01843: not a valid month'

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select to_date('01-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY') from dual
```

Comment: Possibly specify the `nls_language`? If your database (or the connection; unsure) settings aren't set to English, it may not be parsing English month names.

Comment: Better even avoid month names at all. (And two-digit years for that matter.) Use date literals: `select date '2017-03-01' from dual;`.

Comment: More specifically, [`nls_date_language`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28211982/266304) - at least if you’re stuck with that string format. If you have a choice though, use date literals or at least month numbers and an unambiguous date format.